# Trusting a certificate signed by a local CA from an AspNetCore-Api inside docker

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following scenario:
I want to run three services (intranet only) in windows docker containers on a windows host

1. an IdentityServer4
2. an Api (which uses the IdSvr for authorization)
3. a Webclient (which uses the api as Datalayer and the IdSvr for authorization)

All three services are running with asp.netcore 2.1 (with microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime as base) and using certificates signed by a local CA.
The problem I'm facing now is that i cannot get the api or the webclient into trusting these certificates.

E.g. if I call the api the authentication-middleware tries to call the IdSvr but gets an error on GET '~/.well-known/openid-configuration' because of an untrusted ssl certificate.

Is there any way to get the services into trusting every certificate issued by the local CA? I've already tried [this way](http://colmprunty1.azurewebsites.net/2017/06/07/import-and-bind-an-ssl-cert-in-windows-container/) but either I'm doing it wrong or it just doesn't work out.

Imho a docker container must have its own CertStore otherwise none trusted https connection would be possible. So my idea is to get the root certificate from the docker hosts CertStore (which trusts the CA) into the container but I don't know how to achieve this.